# Find contours based on edges and output equipment label

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to code a tool that automatically identifies and alphabetically sorts the images based on equipment number (19-V1083AI). I used the pytesseract library to convert the image to a string after the contours of the equipment label were identified. Although the code runs correctly, it never outputs the equipment number. It's my first time using the pytesseract library and the goodFeaturesToTrack function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Original Image:
[image: Original Image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils #resizeimage
import pytesseract # convert img to string
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Read the image file
image = cv2.imread('Car Images/s3.JPG')

# Resize the image - change width to 500
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)


# Display the original image
cv2.imshow("Original Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# RGB to Gray scale conversion
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("1 - Grayscale Conversion", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Noise removal with iterative bilateral filter(removes noise while preserving edges)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
cv2.imshow("2 - Bilateral Filter", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)


corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,60,0.001,10)

corners = np.int0(corners)

for i in corners:
    x,y = i.ravel()
    cv2.circle(image,(x,y),0,255,-1)
    coord = np.where(np.all(image == (255, 0, 0),axis=-1))
plt.imshow(image)

# Use tesseract to covert image into string
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
print("Equipment Number is:", text)


plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: There are a couple of inconsistencies with your code. You are drawing circles that identify the corners (apparently) but the circles are not shown on the final image. That (possibly) suggests that no corners could be found on the input. Additionally, the corners coordinates are stored in `coord` but that variable is never further used in the snippet you provide. Anyway, what's the goal of all this processing? If you are looking to crop the are with text, something's not right with the algorithm.

Comment: Now, no text is recognized possible because you are passing the whole `image` to tesseract, and the image has a lot of useless info (objects that are not actually text). Also, the label is  little bit skewed. All these things further complicate the OCR. One posible solution is to crop a region of interest (where the actual text is located, dicarding everything else), unwarp the perspective and pass it on to tesseract.